# Edge between matrices misplaced

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like the arrow to point to the "0" of 2nd row, 1st column of the 2nde matrix, here is my code so far:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    
        \matrix (m1) [label skeleton, matrix of math nodes] {
            0 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1\\
        };

        \matrix (m2) at (95pt,0) [label skeleton, matrix of math nodes] {
        1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        };

        \draw[->] (m1-cell-2-3) -- (m2-cell-2-1);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Which outputs this result:

[image]

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Please, make the code snippet into a complete document that we can test without chasing for the needed libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is wrong and `-cell` should be removed.

I also removed `label skeleton` that gives errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m1) [matrix of math nodes] {
    0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1\\
  };
  \matrix (m2) at (95pt,0) [matrix of math nodes] {
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  };
  \draw[->] (m1-2-3) -- (m2-2-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx its working